# How create a generic activity context?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I have the next part of code in which I need to know from what type of activity was the context passed:

```
Activity activity;

        if (mContext instanceof ClientActivity) {
            activity = ((ClientActivity) mContext);
        } else if (mContext instanceof LoginActivity) {
            ((LoginActivity) mContext).onBackPressed();
        } else if (mContext instanceof OnBoardingActivity) {
            ((OnBoardingActivity) mContext).onBackPressed();
        } else if (mContext instanceof HomeActivity) {
            ((HomeActivity) mContext).onBackPressed();
        } else {
            ((Activity) mContext).onBackPressed();
        }
```

Is there a way to make this Activity activity to be generic? To change activity to ClientActivity type if the context is from this activity?

Thnak you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to detect your previous activity is as following:

Make Static Variable in your MainActivity or Constants.java like this:

```
public static String passedContext="MainActivity";
```

and during start Activity set that variable to current activity name like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Next.class);
MainActivity.passedContext = "Main";
startActivity(intent);
```

Now you can check that variable any-were like this

```
if(MainActivity.passedContext.equals("Main")){
//Do Something
}
```

To make it more generic Create parent Activity and Extend all other from that Parent, now in its onPause set value to current class Name like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        MainActivity.passedContext = this.getClass().getCanonicalName(); //Or use any other method to get activityName
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Again you can check that static variable anywhere in application. 
Hope it can Help you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an abstract class extending the `AppCompactActivity` and than extend that from all activities, and place this code in the abstract class.

Example:

```
 abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompactActivity{
 public abstract void handleBackPressed();
     }
```

And than extend BaseActivity from all your classes. When you ovveride that method on each class, do what you need.

But...... looking at your code, this can be done without need of "generic activities"